# Does set_transient() overwrite/update transient option with same key?

Tags: updates, transient

Basically that's the question - I wonder if `set_transient()` overwrites/updates a transient option with the same key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, key (prefixed with string identifying it as transient) is used as option name when value is inserted in database.

Comment: Yes.  As of 4.3.1, handled in [wp-includes/option.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/option.php) using delete_option() + add_option() or update_option().

If using an external object cache, uses wp_cache_set(), defined by memcached as "The value is set whether or not this key already exists in memcached."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, but in my case set_transient() has failed when re-used without delete_transient() first. For some time I thought the problem was that the array I was saving as a transient was too large but that wasn't it. I recommend that you delete the transient first if you're having a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would concur with Jorge on the deletion first - I was having issues with `set_transient` trying to "overwrite" the same transient. The `set_transient` function was updating it, but the return value was false, not true.

A call to `delete_transient` with its name just before `set_transient` solved my issues and `set_transient` would always return true.